# ruby acces hash with variable as key

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a simple (I think) question about hash access. 
I have the following hash (getting form yml file)

```
 {
   "all"=>   {
      "children"=> {
         "TSL-PCM-126"=>    {
            "children"=>  {
               "my_host-TSL-PCM-126"=> {
                  "hosts"=>   {
                     "TSF-W01"=> {
                        "ip"=>"192.168.0.201"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

I store my hostname as variable

```
my_pc="#{`hostname`}" ==> my_pc="TSL-PCM-126"
```

I want to access to the right value but using my_pc variable as key ...

(inventory = Yaml Load of my file)

```
puts inventory["all"]["children"] ==> Work
puts inventory["all"]["children"]["TSL-PCM-126"] ==> Work 
puts inventory["all"]["children"]["#{my_pc}"] ==> NOK :(
```

Comment: You don’t need to interpolate strings: `my_pc = \`hostname\`` and then `puts inventory["all"]["children"][my_pc]` should work.

Comment: I've updated my answer below, `my_pc = \`hostname\`` adds a newline which OP might not be aware of if he is `puts`ing the string.

Comment: Maybe you should use [`Socket.gethostname`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html#method-c-gethostname) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After OP's edit, use

```
my_pc = `hostname`.strip
```

to avoid newline in your string.

This does work as expected,

```
> my_pc
 => "TSL-PCM-126" 
> puts inventory["all"]["children"]["#{my_pc}"]
{"children"=>{"my_host-TSL-PCM-126"=>{"hosts"=>{"TSF-W01"=>{"ip"=>"192.168.0.201"}}
```

You do not need string interpolation though:

```
> inventory["all"]["children"][my_pc]
=> {"children"=>{"my_host-TSL-PCM-126"=>{"hosts"=>{"TSF-W01"=>{"ip"=>"192.168.0.201"}}}}}
```

You either have a typo in your variable/hash or you're trying to assign the return value of `puts`, which is nil.

Answer (score 1):

When I enter

```
`hostname`
```

On my PC I get the response `"dell\n"`. The key thing here is the `\n` at the end. That's an end of line character. So I wonder whether on your PC it is actually returning `my_pc="TSL-PCM-126\n"`. The end of line won't be obvious if you are only using `puts` to examine it. As `"TSL-PCM-126\n" != "TSL-PCM-126"` you don't get a key match.

The [string method `chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) will remove the `\n` character, and give you the match you are after. So:

```
puts inventory["all"]["children"][`hostname`.chomp]
```

Comment: I would recommend `.strip` over `.chomp` to be more robust (strip will remove any trailing whitespace)